# Small caps with macron above using CMU Serif

Tags: fontspec, accents, small-caps, computer-modern

I have some letters with macron above (in fact I have only *ū* and *ā*), they work pretty. But in small caps, when I set `\setmainfont{CMU Serif}` it totally fail. Instead of small cap letter, I get small letter with macron above.

Then, with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\begin{document}
āū

ĀŪ

\textsc{AāūU}
\end{document}
```

I get this rendering

[image]

It’s annoying because without `\setmainfont{CMU Serif}` it work pretty well. But I can’t remove thi font because it fix a lot of other problems, it only cause this one.

So, now their is too solution:

### The quick solution

Just fix the two needed chars with `\newunicodechar{}`

### The long solution

Tell `xelatex` to just use the default font for chars with macron.

To be honest, the quick solution will be widely satisfying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although that font doesn’t have a `smcp` mapping for precomposed characters with the macron, you can instead tell it to use the combining macron accent, U+0304. That enables the quick solution.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{ā}{\accent"0304 a}
\newunicodechar{ū}{\accent"0304 u}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\begin{document}
āū

ĀŪ

\textsc{AāūU}
\end{document}
```

[image: CMU Serif font sample]

You might want the macron over the small capital A shifted to the right.  You can do this with `\skew`.

Comment: I don’t know why but this solution cause a lot of troubles with I compile it. See by yourself (https://framapic.org/TKs4Ok1cbsTP/UTqHER9kXEC1).

Comment: @fauve You might be running an older version of the package or fonts. See @egreg’s solution for something more robust, or replacing `"0304` with `"00AF` might work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can test whether `+smcp` is present in the current font identifier; if it is, use the `\accent` primitive with U+00AF MACRON over the simple letter, otherwise use the composite.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\newunicodechar{ā}{\checksc{a}{ā}}
\newunicodechar{ū}{\checksc{u}{ū}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\checksc}{mm}
 {
  \str_if_in:enTF {\fontname\font}{+smcp}
   { \accent"00AF\scan_stop: #1 }
   { #2 }
 }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_if_in:nn { e } { T,F,TF }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

āū

ĀŪ

\textsc{AāūU}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The instances of ā and ū in normal fonts will copy-paste correctly from the PDF; not those in small caps (I don't think you can do much about it).

A possible improvement for lowering the accent; act on `\kern-0.1ex` to modify the distance.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\newunicodechar{ā}{\checksc{a}{ā}}
\newunicodechar{ū}{\checksc{u}{ū}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\checksc}{mm}
 {
  \str_if_in:enTF {\fontname\font}{+smcp}
   { \fauve_emulate_accent:nn { "00AF } { #1 } }
   { #2 }
 }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_if_in:nn { e } { T,F,TF }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \fauve_emulate_accent:nn
 {
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip\halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr\symbol{#1}\cr\noalign{\kern-0.1ex}\smash{#2}\cr}}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

āū

ĀŪ

\textsc{AāūU}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find the best solution with `\stackinset` from `stackengine` package.
I had to redifine ā with `\stackinset{c}{}{t}{-0.1em}{¯}{a}` As you can see the inset item should be the unicode char *¨* because when I used the TeX command `\={}` (to make macron) the result failed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}



\makeatletter
\newunicodechar{ā}{\stackinset{c}{}{t}{-0.1em}{¯}{a}}
\newunicodechar{ū}{\stackinset{c}{}{t}{-0.1em}{¯}{u}}
\makeatother

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}


\begin{document}
ā

āū

\emph{āū}
\textbf{āū}

ĀŪ

\textsc{AāūU}

\textsc{aāūu}

\end{document}
```